# Infinite loop in iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to learn constructor injection with collections. My Question class as below.

```
public class Question {  
private int id;  
private String name;  
private List<String> answers;  

public Question() {}  
public Question(int id, String name, List<String> answers) {  
    super();  
    this.id = id;  
    this.name = name;  
    this.answers = answers;  
}  

public void displayInfo(){  
    System.out.println(id+" "+name);  
    System.out.println("answers are:");  
    Iterator<String> itr=answers.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        System.out.println(itr);  
    }  
}  

}
```

My Test class as below.

```
public class Test {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

    Question q=(Question)factory.getBean("q");  
    q.displayInfo();  

}  
}
```

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="q" class="DependencyInjection.Question">  
<constructor-arg value="111"></constructor-arg>  
<constructor-arg value="What is java?"></constructor-arg>  
<constructor-arg>  
<list>  
<value>Java is a programming language</value>  
<value>Java is a Platform</value>  
<value>Java is an Island of Indonasia</value>  
</list>  
</constructor-arg>  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Out put as below.

> java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr@15aaf0b3

This is infinite loop. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what is the contents of answers? I think you mean to print something else than itr

Comment: by the way : you arent using constructor injection at all in your example.

Comment: @specializt I edited my question.

Comment: you still are'nt using constructor injection

Comment: @specializt can you explain why? because I'm new for spring

Comment: constructor injection is spring-specific and done via an `@Autowired` annotation on the constructor - this will make spring inject `beans` into to your constructor; which means your constructor will receive valid bean-instances as parameters. Constructor injection is preferred over field injection because such a bean will be highly testable and some people claim its more readable ... i would disagree on that but thats another can of worms.
In short : constructor injection = spring beans as constructor parameters, what you are doing is passing custom parameters via XML to your non-spring bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not advancing the `Iterator`, so your loop never ends.

Change:

```
while(itr.hasNext()){  
    System.out.println(itr);  
}
```

to:

```
while(itr.hasNext()){  
    System.out.println(itr.next());  
}
```

Comment: And also @Lasa you can use System.out.println(String.join(", ", list)); instead of iterating.